# Kaleo workflow in custom portlet

Tags: workflow, liferay, portlet

Steps to create kaleo workflow in custom portlet Liferay 6.1.1 GA2.

Hi,
I am new to liferay. I am using Liferay 6.1.1 GA2 version. Can somebody please provide me the steps to create workflow in custom portlets with some workable samples.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add entity in **service.xml** regarding your workflow portlet.

i.e

```
<entity name="XXWorkflow" local-service="true" remote-service="false">

        <!-- PK fields -->
        <column name="workflowId" type="long" primary="true" />

        <!-- Foreign key columns -->
        <column name="XXd" type="long" />
        <column name="companyId" type="long" />
        <column name="groupId" type="long" />
        <column name="userId" type="long"/>

        <!-- Workflow fields -->

        <!-- Resource -->

        <column name="resourcePrimKey" type="long"></column>
        <column name="title" type="String"></column>
        <column name="status" type="int"></column>
        <column name="statusByUserId" type="long"></column>
        <column name="statusByUserName" type="String"></column>
        <column name="statusDate" type="Date"></column>

        <!-- Finder methods -->

        <finder name="ResourcePrimKey" return-type="RfpWorkflow">
            <finder-column name="resourcePrimKey"></finder-column>
        </finder>

        <finder name="Status" return-type="Collection">
            <finder-column name="status"></finder-column>
        </finder>

        <finder name="R_S" return-type="RfpWorkflow">
            <finder-column name="resourcePrimKey"></finder-column>
            <finder-column name="status"></finder-column>
        </finder>

        <!-- end of workflow columns and finders -->

        <finder return-type="Collection" name="XXId">
            <finder-column name="XXId"></finder-column>
        </finder>

        <reference package-path="com.liferay.portal" entity="WorkflowInstanceLink"></reference>
        <reference package-path="com.liferay.portlet.asset" entity="AssetEntry"></reference>
        <reference package-path="com.liferay.portlet.social" entity="SocialActivity"></reference>

    </entity>
```

**your jsp file:-**

```
submit button action url = "processAction"
```

**Controller**

```
public void processAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)
    throws Exception {

    //do your required stuff

    workflowInitiation(request,response,XX.getXXId(),XX.getXXName());

    }


public void workflowInitiation(ActionRequest actionRequest,
            ActionResponse actionResponse,long XXId,String XXName) throws IOException, PortletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest
                .getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
            System.out.println("Title : " + XXName);
            XXWorkflowImpl xxWorkflow = new XXWorkflowImpl();
            XXWorkflow.setTitle(xxName);
            XXWorkflow.setxxId(xxpId);
            XXWorkflow.setCompanyId(themeDisplay.getCompanyId());
            XXWorkflow.setGroupId(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId());
            ThemeDisplay themeDisplay1 = (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);

            ServiceContext serviceContext;
            try {
                serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(XXPortlet.class.getName(), actionRequest);

                XXWorkflowLocalServiceUtil.addXXWorkflow(XXWorkflow,serviceContext, themeDisplay1.getUserId());
            } catch (PortalException e) {               
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SystemException e) {               
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
    }
```

**Hanlder Class**

```
    public class XXWorkflowHandler extends BaseWorkflowHandler {

    public static final String CLASS_NAME = XXWorkflow.class.getName();

    public String getClassName() {
        return CLASS_NAME;
    }

    public String getType(Locale locale) {
        return LanguageUtil.get(locale, "model.resource." + CLASS_NAME);
    }


    public Object updateStatus(int status,Map<String, Serializable> workflowContext) throws PortalException,
            SystemException {

        long userId = GetterUtil.getLong((String) workflowContext.get(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_USER_ID));
        long resourcePrimKey = GetterUtil.getLong((String) workflowContext.get(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_ENTRY_CLASS_PK));
        ServiceContext serviceContext = (ServiceContext) workflowContext.get("serviceContext");
        return RfpWorkflowLocalServiceUtil.updateStatus(userId, resourcePrimKey,status, serviceContext);

    }

}
```

**Add in your liferay-portlet.xml after portlet-name**

```
<workflow-handler>com.xx.RFPWorkflowHandler</workflow-handler>
```

HTH

Comment: great and easy to understand

Comment: i used this in my message portlet and could get the portlet in the default configuration tab under workflows. But when i enter a message and save it, nothing happens. No entry goes to workflowinstancelink table in db regarding my entry. Is there something i should do more?

Comment: @LuckyBoy please help!!

Comment: @sree did you checked kaleo related tables?

Comment: @LuckyBoy I don't understand that twice it got entered and i received notification, most times it does not. I used WorkflowHandlerRegistryUtil.startWorkflowInstance method to start workflow

Comment: @LuckyBoy I followed the above code. And I would like to see what code should be there in the WorkflowLocalServiceImpl addxxworkflow method. In that method i added this WorkflowHandlerRegistryUtil.startWorkflowInstance method call

Comment: @LuckyBoy Please send me the demo code as well. I am experiencing some issues in this as well...

Comment: @NaveedButt email-id?

Comment: I have done almost everything. Only that a build error is coming, sayaing that I don't have a definition of updateStatus in my Util class. my id is: naveed.butt@gmail.com

Comment: Can u see anything in my workflow tasks when open the entry ?

Comment: yes. the entry shows in the list, but when it opens,null exception raises

Comment: using Service builder , String field having only 75 size .how can we increase the size? Is there a text type ?

Comment: You can increase size in portal-model-hints.xml inside meta-inf folder
<hint name="max-length">10000</hint>

Comment: can you please brief the path ?

Comment: your-project\docroot\WEB-INF\src\META-INF

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>

<model-hints>
 <model name="com.sree">
  <field name="uuid" type="String" />
 
  <field name="s_address" type="String" />
  

  <field name="companyId" type="long" />
  <field name="groupId" type="long" />
  <field name="userId" type="long" />
 </model>
</model-hints>   This is my code in  portal-model-hints.xml . where can i put this code?

Comment: <field name="yourField" type="String">
<hint name="max-length">10000</hint>
</field>

Answer (score 1):

You can find code for Kaleo workflow in custom portlet here for Liferay 6.2

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9B1NsG0lyx6ZmE0UWJCdjk0Mmc/view?usp=sharing

You can find code for Kaleo workflow in custom portlet here for Liferay 6.1
http://sourceforge.net/projects/meeralferay/files/LiferayWorkFlowPortlet/

You can find more specific example for Kaleo workflow in custom portlet which will show only approved feedback list.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9B1NsG0lyx6a3ctUERFNENDTUU/view?usp=sharing