# LifeRay configuring workflow for custom portlet full example

Tags: java, eclipse, liferay, liferay-6

I am a newbie to liferay. It would be really helpful if I could get a **Complete** example on how to configure the workflow to my custom portlet. I have **kaleo** web. My configuration is given below :

```
liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1  
liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0 
Eclipse - juno with liferay IDE installed
```

I tried googling a lot, but i couldn't find a full sample which i can clearly follow. I found the examples which were too hard for me to understand. I am looking for a full example, let it be even giving a hello world, using an approval system, right from creating the portlet and all the configurations. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Good luck with that! :-) We spent about a month to make Kaleo work 6.1 but had to fall back to creating a custom JBPM integration within Liferay (even with the help of LR support and official "Kaleo experts" we ran into a bugs with a simple split and wasn't able to use it).

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853340/kaleo-workflow-in-custom-portlet/17856888#17856888...

Comment: @LuckyBoy Thankyou. It was my mistake. I got it working by your example itself.